# Does core data support custom domain object models?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I have done the following to try and answer this question:

- I have scanned the Apple documentation on [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html)
- I have done this very good tutorial: [Core Data from Scratch](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-from-scratch-core-data-stack--cms-20926)
- I have scanned other articles in an attempt to answer this question

**Further detail on my question:**

I have an existing iOS application. To achieve persistence, I am currently, by hand, marshaling and unmarshalling JSON files which I store in a directory on the phone. I would like to instead use Core Data in the same kind of way that you might use Hibernate or another ORM tool with my ***existing*** domain model.

Which is to say I would like to have something like:

```
MyDomainObjectDAO
    save( myDomainObject )
    load( id )   
    etc. etc.
```

Where the implementation of those methods involves handing an instance of myDomainObject to something like an ORM context which then stores the object. C'est possible?

I imagine that I could copy all the values from my existing object structure into managed objects created by the core data Apple tools, but I wanted to ask if there was a better way to do this. I would like to keep my convenience methods on my domain objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you are looking for [RestKit](http://restkit.org). What you will do is create a relationship between your object model and your JSON. You will find that you can almost do it all on the fly without creating any NSObjects manually or parsing any JSON. All you have to do is create the CoreData scheme and create some mapping instances. RestKit will convert your incoming JSON to these objects before persisting them into CoreDate. RestKit is awesome though a bit slow!